# prevent checkbox to be checked when clicked unless it is unprotected

Tags: excel, vba

I want to prevent Excel active-x checkebox located in protected cells to be clicked unless the cells protection is lifted. How to do this? the code I am using is this one:

```
   Private Sub ChkB_Attachments_Click()
    If ChkB_Attachments.Value = True Then
        SelectFile
        Else
        If ChkB_Attachments.Value = False Then
            DeleteAttachment
        End If
    End If
   End Sub
```

I don't want `ChkB_Attachments` to be clicked unless previous conditions are set. If I protect the Cell in which Checkbox is inserted, this has no effect. I already got answer from `Xabier` for Radio buttton but applying same method gave no result. Any suggestion?

Comment: Ensure that the Active-X object (not the cell) is locked (find the lock option in the "Format" menu), then protect the worksheet.

Comment: You say "unless previous conditions are set". What conditions are those? Does this have to be done using sheet protection, or could clicking it be prevented another way?